# What am I doing wrong here? (AppleScript remove multiple parts of string)

Tags: string, macos, scripting, applescript

I'm trying to clean up the string so that it removes **"//name@"** and **"deletethispart.file"** from *"//name@main.domain.com/directory01/directory02/deletethispart.file"*

```
set mainString to "//name@main.domain.com/directory01/directory02/deletethispart.file"
set cleanUpTerms to {"//name@", "deletethispart.file"}
repeat with i from 1 to count of cleanUpTerms
    set text item delimiters to item i of cleanUpTerms
    set cleanURL to text items of mainString
    set text item delimiters to ""
    set mainString to cleanURL
end repeat
```

It's not working :(

Comment: Note that the text item delimiters can be a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate the text items at the end of the repeat loop.

Renaming `cleanURL` with `textItems` makes it clearer

```
set mainString to "//name@main.domain.com/directory01/directory02/deletethispart.file"
set cleanUpTerms to {"//name@", "deletethispart.file"}
repeat with i from 1 to count of cleanUpTerms
    set text item delimiters to item i of cleanUpTerms
    set textItems to text items of mainString
    set text item delimiters to ""
    set mainString to textItems as text
end repeat
```

Comment: wow thanks! that was such a quick answer too. Awesome. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

As red_menace said, text item delimiters can be a list. it means you do not need a loop for each delimiter:

```
set mainString to "//name@main.domain.com/directory01/directory02/deletethispart.file"
set cleanUpTerms to {"//name@", "deletethispart.file"}
set text item delimiters to cleanUpTerms

set cleanURL to text items of mainString
set text item delimiters to ""
set mainString to cleanURL as text
```